# Google Script - Execute only if cell contains a certain string of text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Completely new to using the AppsScript in Google but I came across a script that would allow GoogleSheets to count cells if coloured, and it automatically updates thanks to that last bit of code that sets a random value that essentially triggers a recalculation:

```
// Unsed third argument
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef,unUsed) {
var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
// The regex matches the parentheses as an array, gets the arguments as a string,
// then splits the arguments on the comma into another array
var arrayOfArguments = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\)/).pop().trim().split(',');
// Get the first argument which is the range
var countRangeAddress = arrayOfArguments[0];
// Get the second argument, which is the reference color
var colorRefAddress = arrayOfArguments[1];
var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
var countCells = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
countCells = countCells + 1;
return countCells;
};

// If Cell A1 has ColouredCells, Writes a random number to B1
function onEdit(e) {
if SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1')="ColouredCells" {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(Math.random());}

}
```

Specifically I'm looking to edit the last part of the code so that this script only runs on sheets which I'd like it to (instead of randomly changing my B1 cell on all sheets I touch). As per the comments I'd like it to only run if cell A1 has the string "ColouredCells". Sorry newbie to all this so apologies if this is a really simple ask! Appreciate any help I can get on this one, I've tried googling quite a few different things but can't seem to to find the solution on this one!

This is the part I specifically need help with.

```
// If Cell A1 has ColouredCells, Writes a random number to B1
function onEdit(e) {
if SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1')="ColouredCells" {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B1').setValue(Math.random());}

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To run the code for specific sheets only you have to first get the name of the sheet and with an if-statement run the code as you wish

```
function onEdit(e){
  // code
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  if ("Sheet 1" === sheet.getName() || "Sheet 2" === sheet.getName()) {
    // Run your code
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to use the code on multiple sheets though. I think i'm only really looking for the part of the code thats putting in a random maths value to only run if say a specific cell contains the string text "ColouredCells"

Comment: According to the documentation:
onEdit(e) runs when a user changes a value in a spreadsheet. So your function onEdit will be called anytime you edit a cell in any sheet of your spreadsheet. In your post you say **Specifically I'm looking to edit the last part of the code so that this script only runs on sheets which I'd like it to (instead of randomly changing my B1 cell on all sheets I touch).** This is done with the code above. I am going to adjust it so it is a bit more clear

Comment: For getting the text value check SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').getValue()